# Using update_batch to increment fields in database Single quotes automatically added

Tags: php, mysql

Using update_batch to increment fields in database Single quotes automatically added
calling function code

`$this->db->update_batch("FundCategory",$create_data,'fundCategoryId')`

My codigniter last query is

```
UPDATE `FundCategory` SET `fundCategoryUpdatedById` = CASE 
WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '4' THEN '20000045'
WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '4' THEN '20000045'
ELSE `fundCategoryUpdatedById` END, `fundCategoryValue` = CASE 
WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '4' THEN 'fundCategoryValue + 100'
WHEN `fundCategoryId` = '4' THEN 'fundCategoryValue + 200'
ELSE `fundCategoryValue` END
WHERE `fundCategoryId` IN('4','4')
```

I want to remove single quotes after then when increment "fundCategoryValue" column

Comment: Can you update the post with some more lines from your PHP code

Comment: Ravinder Reddy  thanks for ur comment but Akshay Hegde  solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this by modifying core**

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L2019

**Of function**

```
public function set_update_batch($key, $index = '', $escape = NULL)
{
..
..
..
}
```

**From**

```
'value'=>($escape === FALSE ? $v2 : $this->escape($v2))
```

**To**

```
'value'=>(is_array($v2) ? $v2[0] : ($escape === FALSE ? $v2 : $this->escape($v2)))
```

and give input like below

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'fundCategoryId' => '3' ,
      'fundCategoryValue' => '500' , // generates with single quotes

   ),
   array(
      'fundCategoryId' => '4' ,
      'fundCategoryValue' => array('fundCategoryValue + 100') // generates without single quotes

   )
);
```

**On old CI 2.2.x**

**Modify DB_active_rec.php**

**From**

```
            if ($escape === FALSE)
            {
                $clean[$this->_protect_identifiers($k2)] = $v2;
            }
            else
            {
                $clean[$this->_protect_identifiers($k2)] = $this->escape($v2);
            }
```

**To**

```
 $clean[$this->_protect_identifiers($k2)] = (is_array($v2)? $v2[0] : ( ($escape === FALSE) ? $v2 : $this->escape($v2) ));
```

Comment: Akshay Hegde very very good answer it solve my problem completey